# Use nginx to redirect to port 4000

Tags: nginx

I know there are already many requests of this kind. But I can't forward it to another port via ngnix.

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
---
version: '3'
services:
  umami:
    container_name: umami
    image: ghcr.io/umami-software/umami:postgresql-latest
    ports:
      - "4000:3000"
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgresql://umami:umami@db:5432/umami
      DATABASE_TYPE: postgresql
      HASH_SALT: ovD4Q594iOC6RfjgB8
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: always
  db:
    container_name: umami_db
    image: postgres:12-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: umami
      POSTGRES_USER: umami
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: umami
    volumes:
      - ./sql/schema.postgresql.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/schema.postgresql.sql:ro
      - umami-db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    restart: always
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx:1.23.4-alpine
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
volumes:
  umami-db-data:
```

nginx/nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location /umami {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4000/;
    }
}
```

Umami successfully running at http://localhost:4000/

Got "Bad Gateway" with logs:

```
2023-04-15 17:26:24 2023/04/15 15:26:24 [error] 20#20: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.19.0.1, server: , request: "GET /umami/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:4000//", host: "localhost"
2023-04-15 17:26:24 172.19.0.1 - - [15/Apr/2023:15:26:24 +0000] "GET /umami/ HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If you got also `502` with the suggested `proxy_pass http://umami:3000`, it means the service `umami` does not listen on port `3000`. Is the service running?

Comment: Yes, the service is running and available with http://localhost:4000/ outside of docker

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `localhost`, you should use the service name of `umami`.

```
proxy_pass http://umami:3000/;
```

The reason is that `localhost` in this case points to the `localhost` of your nginx container, not the one of the hosting machine.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but I'm still getting a Bad Gateway error. 
Logs:


2023-04-15 17:41:33 172.19.0.1 - - [15/Apr/2023:15:41:33 +0000] "GET /umami/ HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
2023-04-15 17:41:33 2023/04/15 15:41:33 [error] 20#20: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.19.0.1, server: , request: "GET /umami/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.19.0.3:4000//", host: "localhost"

Comment: I'm sorry, you should use the internal port aswel so you can redirect to port 3000 instead of 4000, as 4000 is not known inside of your container

Comment: ```proxy_pass http://umami:3000/;```

unfortunately doesn't work either